# Javascript Date.setHours() is modifying a Date object that I did not reference, uses wrong day

Tags: javascript

I want to create a list of date objects that are spaced some hours apart. So, for 10 hours it would be: "Monday, 20:00 --> Tuesday, 6:00 --> Tuesday, 16:00" and so forth. My idea has been to use a "base" date, like "Monday 20:00" in the previous example, so "base.setHours(20), base.setHours(30), base.setHours(40)" to get that result.

But once I call setHours() in a way that makes the Date object's "day" change, that change is permanent. So, after base.setHours(30), base.setHours(40) starts from Tuesday, not from Monday, which is what I want. I tried to fix this behavior by having a temporary variable **loopday** that stores the true original date **base**, but Javascript reaches back in time to change **base**!

For example, the output of this code:

```
var base = new Date(2015, 1, 4);
for(var hr = 0; hr < 50; hr += 10)
{
    var loopday = base;
    loopday.setHours(hr);
    window.alert([base.getDay(), base.getHours()]);
}
```

is "[4, 0], [4, 10], [4, 20], [5, 6], [6, 16], [8, 2]". Firstly, I would expect it to be all "[4, 0]"s because I did not touch "day" at all; I only modified "loopday". But also, after the day switches from January 4 to January 5, the day of month is wrong too. It should be "..., [5, 6], [5, 16], [6, 2]".

On a practical level, how could I modify that code so that **loopday**'s Date and Hours are **[4, 0], [4, 10], [4, 20], [5, 6], [5, 16], [6, 2]**? On an understanding level, why did Javascript modify **base**, and what accounts for the weird behavior on the day of month for the last two outputs?

Comment: base and loopday are references to same date object .... changes to either variable change the  object they both reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a reference to a Date instance from one variable to another does not make a copy. You have to explicitly make a new date:

```
  var loopday = new Date(base);
```

In general, references to any sort of object in JavaScript are what get passed around in assignments, function calls, and function returns. Copies must be made explicitly.